# Why does row_number() window function of POSTGRESQL not working in psycopg2 but works in command line or pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have following query to find out row number of a certain data.

```
cursor.execute("select row_number from (select row_number() over(order by date desc), * from contest where date <= %s order by date LIMIT (select count(*) from contest where date <= %s) - 1) as new WHERE date = %s", (today, today ,date))
```

When I execute this query, I get this error message

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: select row_number from (select row_number() over(order by d...
```

And I execute the same query in pgadmin4 or in postgresql command line like below. It works fine.

```
select row_number from (select row_number() over(order by date desc), * from contest where date <= '2017-5-5' order by date LIMIT (select count(*) from contest where date <='2017-5-5' ) - 1) as new WHERE date = '2017-2-1'
```

I use latest version of postgresql and psycopg2.

I am stuck here. I can't find answer.
I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Tometzky's test, it's highly likely that the issue is a non-printable character or similar.

Try turning on `log_error_verbosity = verbose` and checking the PostgreSQL error log for more details.

Also examine your source file with non-printable character display turned on.

Otherwise.... how sure are you that you're connected to the same DB and same postgres version from Psycopg2 as from psql?

Comment: I think it has something to do with character. I just copied the query into my pgadmin4 and it show a red dot in front of select and it says it's '\ufeff'. Does this mean that some broken code got into the query and can't translate? How do I fix this?

Comment: Thank you. you were right. There was this \ufeff character in the file. Not just one place, there were six of them. All right in front of select keyword. Do you happen to know how to check if I have bad character in my file and remove them?

Comment: That's `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`. I'm unsure how it's getting there, what editor do you use? are you copying & pasting queries back and forth between things a lot?

Comment: Yes, in fact that's exactly what I did. I wrote queries in pgadmin4 and copied it and pasted into python file on pycharm. There is encoding option in pycharm, but wasn't sure how to use it to get rid of the characters. So I just replaced all \ufeff character with empty string. But that works only when I know what character I should look for. I wonder if there is a way to check such a thing systematically. What's ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE? and how to spot it on file?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have no idea what your query is trying to do, there's no syntax error and it worked, when I created a SSCCE from it:

```
import psycopg2, datetime

conn = psycopg2.connect("")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("create temporary table contest(id serial primary key, date date not null)")
cursor.execute("insert into contest (date) values (%s)", ("2000-01-01",))

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
cursor.execute("""
    select row_number from (
        select row_number() over(order by date desc), *
        from contest
        where date <= %s
        order by date
        LIMIT ( select count(*) from contest where date <= %s) - 1
    ) as new
    WHERE date = %s""",
    (today, today, date)
)
```

Works with Python-3.5/psycopg2-2.7.1 and Python-2.7/psycopg2-2.6.2. The problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, problem was elsewhere. It was a character problem.